# PHP - What Regex should I use to validate an input to be either empty or 4 digits?

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this PHP code:

```
$pCode = $_POST["postcode"];
if (!empty($pCode)) {
    $pCodePattern = "/^\d{4}$/";
    if (!preg_match($pCodePattern, $pCode)) {
        $pCodeMsg = "<span> post code must be 4 digits </span>";
    }
}
```

When I run the code the error message is still shown.

Comment: You can also use :   <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="4">  For Simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that the `\d{4}` pattern can be optional:

```
$pCodePattern = "/^(?:\d{4})?$/";
                   ^^^     ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX3jK7/1)

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of stirng
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group (the `?` quantifier matches one or zero occurrences)

  - `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `)?` - end of optional non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any Regex

```
$pCode = $_POST["postcode"];
    $len=1;
    while ($pCode >= 10)
    {
      $pCode = ($pCode / 10);
      ++$len;
    }
    if($len != 4){
    $pCodeMsg = "<span> post code must be 4 digits </span>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pCode = $_POST["postcode"];
if (!empty($pCode)) {
    $pCodePattern = "^(\d{4}|\s*)$";
    if (!preg_match($pCodePattern, $pCode)) {
        $pCodeMsg = "<span> post code must be 4 digits </span>";
    }
}
```